# jQuery mobile + spring controller dynamic listview

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, jquery-mobile

i'm using jquery listview to display list of course name. the data needs to take from the controller. when i run it, nothing display in the page.

this is my html

```
   <div id="courseName">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and this is my script

```
$('#registeredClasses').live('pageshow', function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getRegisteredClassesData.html',
     dataType: 'json',

        success: function(json_results){
        listItems = $('#courseName').find('ul');
        $.each(json_results.rows, function(key) {
           html = '<li <h3><a href="index1.html?id=' + [json_results.rows[key].courseId] +'"rel="external">'+json_results.rows[key].courseName+'</h3>';
          html += '<p><br> Course name: '+json_results.rows[key].courseName+'</p></a></li>';


        listItems.append(html);
        });
          $('#courseName ul').listview('refresh');
 $.mobile.pageLoading(true);     
    }
});
});
```

and this is where it call from controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getRegisteredClassesData.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody CustomPagedResultResponse getRegisteredClassesData(
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session) {
    CustomPagedResultResponse paging = new CustomPagedResultResponse();

    log.debug("getRegisteredClassesData.html:");  
    log.debug("rows:"+request.getParameter("rows"));
    log.debug("courseId:"+session.getAttribute("courseId")); 
    log.debug("page:"+request.getParameter("page"));
    log.debug("sidx:"+request.getParameter("sidx"));
    log.debug("sord:"+request.getParameter("sord"));
    //String loginId = (request.getSession().getAttribute("loginId")).toString();
    //String page =(request.getSession().getAttribute("page")).toString(); 
    //String row = (request.getSession().getAttribute("row")).toString();

    String page = request.getParameter("page");
    int pageSize = new Integer(request.getParameter("rows")).intValue();
    StringBuffer condition = new StringBuffer();
    if (request.getParameter("sidx") != null && !request.getParameter("sidx").equals("")) {
        condition.append(request.getParameter("sidx"));
        condition.append(" ");
    }
    if (request.getParameter("sord") != null && !request.getParameter("sord").equals("")) {
        condition.append(request.getParameter("sord"));
    }
    log.debug("condition: " + condition.toString());
    log.debug("page:"+page);
    log.debug("row:"+pageSize);

    String courseType = "%";

    UserProfile userProfile = (UserProfile)session.getAttribute("userProfile");


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Retrieve  Total Record first
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    RegisteredClassesSearch search = new RegisteredClassesSearch();
    search.setLanguage("ENU");
    search.setLoginRowId(userProfile.getContactRowId());
    search.setRegNo(null);
    search.setAction("1");
    search.setCourseType(courseType);
    search.setPage(null);
    search.setPageSize(null);
    search.setOrderBy(null);

    Integer recordCount = registeredClassesService.getTotalAccounts(search);
    log.debug("*****Training Controller Total record:"+recordCount);
    System.out.println("*****Training Controller Total record:"+recordCount);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Retrieve  Total Record first
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(recordCount>0){

        System.out.println("******** Login Id:"+userProfile.getContactRowId());
        System.out.println("******** Course Type:"+courseType);
        System.out.println("******** Page Size:"+pageSize);
        System.out.println("******** Page:"+page);
        System.out.println("******** Order By:"+condition);

        List<RegisteredClassesTest> registeredClassesView = registeredClassesService.getAccounts(search);

        paging.setRows(registeredClassesView);
    }else{
        paging.setRows(null);
    }


    paging.setRecords(String.valueOf(recordCount));
    paging.setPage(page);
    int total = recordCount % pageSize == 0 ? recordCount / pageSize : recordCount / pageSize + 1;
    paging.setTotal(String.valueOf(total));

    return paging;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  try this one,
```

you should close `<li>` tag and are you sure data comes from the sever?

```
html = '<li > <h3><a href="index1.html?id=' + [json_results.rows[key].courseId] +'"rel="external">'+json_results.rows[key].courseName+'</h3>';
      html += '<p><br> Course name: '+json_results.rows[key].courseName+'</p></a></li>';


    listItems.append($(html));
```

Comment: the data is not from the controller, but i used controller to retrieve my data in database. i used spring framework. mostly i see they used php, that why i can't find the right solution. i also not sure weather my code i post is correct or not, but i tried to put urs, it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

use json_results.d instead of json_results.row.

```
 $.each(json_results.d, function(index, item) { 

html = '<li > <h3><a href="index1.html?id=' + item.courseId+'"rel="external">'+ item.courseName+'</h3>';
  html += '<p><br> Course name: '+item.courseName+'</p></a></li>';
```

}

Comment: i think the html and script is correct, but my controller there's some prob. do i need to modify my controller?

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i've success already.. this is my script. for the data, i hard coded it first..

```
$('#registeredClasses').live('pageshow', function(){
    var rowInput = "1";
    var pageInput = "1";

    $.ajax({
     url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getRegisteredClassesDetails.html',
     data: ( {rows : rowInput , page : pageInput}),
     type: 'POST',

    success: function(json_results){
        $('#list').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"</ul>');
        listItems = $('#list').find('ul');
        $.each(json_results.rows, function(key) {
          html = '<li <h3><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getRegisteredClassesDetails.html?id=' + [json_results.rows[key].courseId] 
                +'"rel="external">'+json_results.rows[key].courseName+'</h3>';
        listItems.append(html);
        });

    $('#list ul').listview();
    $.mobile.pageLoading(true);      
    }
});
});
```

Comment: ok..cool . yours '<li>' tag  is not closed. check it is. '<li <h3>'

Comment: ya, thanks. i've change it already.. but if you close the li, the interface will be different a bit